# Using Kerberos Tokens in C#

Tags: c#, .net, kerberos

I'm trying use Kerberos tokens directly in C# using the `KerberosSecurityTokenProvider`. Unfortunately, the documentation on its use is very limited and I've not had much success. I've written the following sample test application:

```
var oProvider = new KerberosSecurityTokenProvider("MACHINENAME",TokenImpersonationLevel.Identification);
var oToken = (KerberosRequestorSecurityToken)oProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

Console.WriteLine(oToken.ValidFrom);
Console.WriteLine(oToken.ValidTo);
Console.WriteLine(oToken.Id);

var abRequest = oToken.GetRequest();
var sId = oToken.Id;

try
{
    var oReceivedToken = new KerberosReceiverSecurityToken(abRequest, sId);
    var oAuthenticator = new KerberosSecurityTokenAuthenticator();

    var oCol = oAuthenticator.ValidateToken(oReceivedToken);
    foreach (var o in oCol)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(o.Id);
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Where `MACHINENAME` is the name of my machine. It successfully gets a Kerberos Token, but when I try to validate it, I get:

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException: The AcceptSecurityContext failed. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed
```

Which leaves me with a number of questions:

- Is this the correct way to get/validate Kerberos Tokens in C#?
- Why is it trying to perform a login if I am just saying I want to use the token for identification?
- Is the error due to my code, or are there domain configuration issues that also need to be addressed?

Any comments on how to use your own Kerberos tokens in .NET?

Comment: Why do you do that? Use SSPI. You should not directly use Kerberos.

Comment: I want to use be able to extract the token to be used to identify users as part of my own protocol.

Comment: You would receive that from GSS-API/SSPI too because it knows who initiated the security context.